# Not able to cover test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Below is my class for which i am creating test clas, but not able to cover.

**Class**

```
public with sharing class Opportunityoncontact {

    @TestVisible private List<Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c> oppz{ get; set; }
    private Contact cntact { get; set; }
    private Set<Id> oppoid { get; set; }
    public Opportunityoncontact(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.cntact= (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c> getOppz()
    {
        Contact con = [Select id FROM Contact where id = :cntact.id];
        oppz = [Select id,OpportunityId__r.StageName,OpportunityId__r.CloseDate,OpportunityId__r.Amount__c,OpportunityId__r.Name, Name from Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c where ContactId__c = :con.id];
        return oppz;
    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class TestOpportunityoncontact {



    private static testMethod void testInsertOcr(){


        //Opportunityoncontact ocr = new Opportunityoncontact(new ApexPages.StandardController(new Contact()));
        Contact ocr11 = new Contact();

         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(ocr11);  
        Opportunityoncontact ocr = new Opportunityoncontact(sc);  
        List<Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c> oppz = new List<Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c>();
        oppz=[Select id,OpportunityId__r.StageName,OpportunityId__r.CloseDate,OpportunityId__r.Amount__c,OpportunityId__r.Name, Name from Opportunity_Contact_Roles__c where ContactId__c = :ocr11.id];


    }

}
```

**Error**

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert:

```
Contact ocr11 = new Contact();
insert ocr11;
```

in your test so that an ID is assigned and it can be queried in `Opportunityoncontact`.

(That error message occurs when you assign a query result to a single object reference rather than a list reference but no rows are returned in the query result.)